# JavaScript codes to add hour, minute and seconds

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JavaScript code that takes input for Hour, minute and seconds and adds them to show the total hour, minute and seconds. If the total minute is greater than 60 total hour will get increases by 1. Similarly for seconds.
But when the total minutes are over 60 Total hours are getting +2 instead of +1. My code is as below. Can anyone please let me know what went wrong.

```
let currentSecond, currentMinute, currentHour, totalTimeInSecond;
let totalSecond, totalMinute, totalHour;
let arrHour, arrMinute, arrSecond;
totalSecond = 0;
totalMinute = 0;
totalHour = 0;

document
  .getElementById("secondValue")
  .addEventListener("keypress", function(mojo) {
    if (mojo.keyCode === 13) {
      totalHour += parseInt(document.getElementById("hourValue").value, 10);
      totalMinute += parseInt(document.getElementById("minuteValue").value, 10);
      if (totalMinute >= 60) {
        totalMinute = totalMinute - 60;
        totalHour++;
      }
      totalSecond += parseInt(document.getElementById("secondValue").value, 10);
      if (totalSecond >= 60) {
        totalSecond = totalSecond - 60;
        totalMinute++;
      }

      console.log(totalHour);
      console.log(totalMinute);
      console.log(totalSecond);

      //   currentHour = document.getElementById("hourValue").value;
      //   currentMinute = document.getElementById("minuteValue").value;
      //   currentSecond = document.getElementById("secondValue").value;
      //   console.log(currentHour);
      //   console.log(currentMinute);
      //   console.log(currentSecond);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Note that your code will fail if given input values of `0:59:60` - instead of outputting `1:00:00` it will output `0:60:00`. You will want to check the seconds first for overflow, then the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript alone

```js
console.clear();

d = new Date()
d.setUTCHours(12)
d.setUTCMinutes(61)
d.setUTCSeconds(62)
console.log(d.getUTCHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') 
  + ':' 
  + d.getUTCMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') 
  + ':' 
  + d.getUTCSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')
) // 13:02:02
```